# Is this repo missing files, or am I using it wrong?

Tags: android, git, qr-code, zbar

I'm trying to use Zbar for android for scanning QR codes. I need something minimal that only scans qr codes. That's why Im not using zxing.

https://github.com/ZBar/ZBar/tree/master/android

I tried adding it to my code as a module, but it seems like the library itself is missing from the android folder. There is no jar file or library source code. the only source code is in the example.

there is no "ZBar-Android-SDK" folder as mentioned in the readme.

am I missing something or is the repo missing something?

one thing to note is that the project is for eclipse (I assume) and I'm using Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the pre-built SDK instead of the source code:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/files/AndroidSDK/

Comment: oh thank you, I was going crazy. There is no link to this page from their github OR their zbar.sourceforge page.

Comment: It's very well hidden, but on the bottom of the downloads page there is "Browse all ZBar releases".